# Sharing through Facebook SDK I am getting the following error in iphone app?Can you suggest me what mistake might me I made?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios7

While I am trying to share something through facebook SDK I am getting error like

**"Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0xd1700a0 {error={     code = 12;     message = "(#12) username is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher";     type = OAuthException; }}".**

Can any one help me which kind of error will be? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, apparently, you're using a old method/parameter: `code = 12; message = "(#12) username is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher`. And without any code, hard to tell what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0
there is a clear explanation of the facebook error code in the link given above

according to that your error means: login status or access token has expired, been revoked, or is otherwise invalid - Handle expired access tokens (unless subcode is present)